# Adding new data error

Tags: sql, database

When i'm running this code, it says:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

On the underlined area, can some one help me with this.

```
namespace ASP_05
{
 public partial class AddEmployee : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    public DataSet getDataset(string query)
    {

        String sConn = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=medewerkers;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        da.Dispose();
        return ds;
    }

    protected void toevoegen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String vn = voornaam.ToString();
        String an = voornaam.ToString();
        String a = voornaam.ToString();
        String t = voornaam.ToString();

        string query = "INSERT INTO tblMedewerkers (voornaam, achternaam, afdeling, toestelnummer) VALUES ('" + vn + "','" + an + "','" + a + "','" + t + "')";
        this.execSQL(query);
    }

    public int execSQL(string query)
    {
        String sConn = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=medewerkers;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConn);
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return i;
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you are inserting in the table for a particular column is more in size than what you have defined in the table. Hence you are getting this error. Go through your column definitions and also through the records you are inserting and check if any of the column have less size than data you are inserting